# Tool to do batch lookup of DNS servers assigned to specific domains

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

While there are a handful of tools that let you drop a list of domain names and return any DNS record pertaining to those domain names, I have not been able to find a tool that returns the DNS servers assigned to each domain.

Could someone recommend a tool that would accomplish this? Windows (preferably) or Linux (command line) would work.

Thanks!

PS: not sure if this Q fits here or prowebmaster... I apologize in advance if I chose the wrong stacksite.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870090/batch-script-to-get-website-ip-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`dig`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) tool:

```
dig +nssearch google.com
```

Comment: thanks, i am aware of dig, but that is not what I am looking for as I would have to script something to batch dig.

Comment: @Gaia: dig support multiple queries by default, but there is no real separation of what result goes with what query if you are looking at it programmatically. Try `dig +nssearch google.com yahoo.com` to see what I mean. If you are eyeballing it, though, it usually is fairly obvious.

Comment: @answered thanks! now i got what i need via a [dig web interface](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=google.com%0D%0Ayahoo.com&type=NS&colorize=on&onlyfirst=on&ns=resolver&useresolver=208.67.222.222&nameservers=)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `nslookup set type=ns "domain"` to query the name servers for a particular domain.

Comment: thanks, i am aware of nslookup, but that is not what I am looking for as I would have to script something to batch nslookup.